# How to ask the question w.r.t protecting the lens so that it doesn't appear a troll post?

Tags: discussion

I have been called a "***troll***" for the following question:

> **How to take care of a lens (besides using a hood) while walking down a road?**
>
> One way - hold your lens's mouth down while walking down the road, Another - don't shoot while facing fire, lights, sun etc. What else?

Well, this is what "I" could think of. I have read about lens getting damaged due to flare so thought of asking how to handle it with care.

Now, how to make this question *"**non-trollish**"*? :rolleyes:

Should this question be broken down into pieces, and get each piece into a different thread?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your original question. Is it: "Do you need to protect your lens from flare damage whilst carrying the camera and if so, other than a hood how would you go about protecting it?"  If so, then 'put your lens cap on' seems like an obvious response... As it stands, the question could easily be interpretted to give answers like 'rest your hand on the lens, so that nobody disconnects it and walks off with it while you're not looking'...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure what was meant by "trollish".  I think the issue was that you asked a bunch of seemingly random, unrelated things.  If the question deals with how to protect your lens while "walking down the road", what does that have to do with shooting into lights/torch/fire?

If you were to ask "I'm going on a cruise (or to the beach). How can I prevent dropping my camera in the ocean" I think it would be the same.  Vague and more about common sense than photography.  Begging for answers like "don't drop it" or "leave it at home"

But if you asked "is it true I can damage my lens if it's pointing at the sun too long?" or "My lens bangs against things when I walk, how can I prevent that"  it would be easier to answer and sound more like you have a specific concern or question.

Comment: Mike, I was under an impression that flare (strong lights) damage the lens/camera. Is that wrong? If it is, then for sure this question is pointless.

Comment: Lenses being made of glass, like windows, strong lights, even the sun, go through them harmlessly, except that lenses also focus, so pointing directly at the sun you could probably heat up the lens, or damage sensors.  Photographers take pictures into the sun all the time.  But if you left it, like a magnifying glass, I suppose you could start a fire eventually.  So yes and no I suppose.  Flare is an effect on images due to scattering of light, see here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_flare

Comment: Where did the troll comment come from?  Whoever made it might be better to explain what they meant by it.

Comment: Someone called Nick said "It seems like a trollish attempt". I'll read about flare more. BTW, I was worried about car head lights, torch, tubelights, street lights getting into the lens and damaging it, hence the question. :doh: